# Xelatex is not compiling

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I am trying to include Unicode characters in a latex template, which look like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{acl2015}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\newfontfamily{\malayalam}{Meera}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}


\section{\malayalam ന മ പ ഗ ച ദ തീ}

{\malayalam ന മ പ ഗ ച ദ തീ \\ 
ന മ പ ഗ ച ദ തീ \\
ന മ പ ഗ ച ദ തീ \\
ന മ പ ഗ ച ദ തീ \\}

Back to english again...


The following instructions are directed to authors of papers submitted
to ACL-2015 or accepted for publication in its proceedings. All
authors are required to adhere to these specifications. Authors are
required to provide a Portable Document Format (PDF) version of their
papers. \textbf{The proceedings are designed for printing on A4
paper.}
```

But It gives  me errors:

```
! LaTeX Error:  this package currently works only with XeTeX You are not using XeTeX, so we are exiting cleanly!Continuing may lead to 'unavailable font metrics' errors!.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...sname\relax\expandafter\notXeTeXformat\fi
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"!! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.!! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".!! See the fontspec documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... }
```

I am using Windows 7 and Tex Maker as Editor,Xelatex is also installed in the system.

Any help??

Update: When I tried to compile using command line mode, It give "fatal file error"

Comment: The error says that you are running the file with pdfTeX not XeTeX: just being installed isn't enough.

Comment: `acl2015.sty` can be found ... where?

Comment: http://acl2015.org/call_for_papers.html, Here you can find acl.sty

Comment: @karu: Ah yes. It's probably not important for the basic question all. Joseph already gave a clue

Comment: When use command line interface of xelatex, It give fatal file format error @SoundsOfSilence

Comment: What command are you using to compile the file?  I would expect it should be `xelatex my-acl-paper.tex`.

Comment: Yeah, Using the xelatex filename.tex

Comment: Which texsystem are you using? Miktex or TeXlive?

Comment: I am using Miktex

Comment: In Quick Build, change it to XeLaTeX and compile again

Comment: Go to miktex settings (user version, not admin), tab formats. Select xelatex and click on build. Do you get an error?

Comment: LaTeX Font Info: Try loading font information for OMS+Meera(0) on input line
171.
LaTeX Font Info: No file OMSMeera(0).fd. on input line 171.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/Meera(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font) using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font) for symbol `textbullet' on input line 171.